# Sum quarter data according to months completed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to sum quarter data kept in column `C2` to `W2`. In cell `W1` is the number of months passed, which for current purpose is 7. The sum would be in cell `W2`. As 7 months have passed, hence need to sum `C2`, `D2` and `1/3* E2` and show the value in `W2`. `E2` is multiplied by `1/3` because 7th month is 1/3rd of the 3rd quarter. The quarters are financial quaters, but doesn't always start from a FY start.

Hope this is clear. If someone could point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when we get to the end of this FY? Do you still want to include C2 or do you start from G2? What will W1 show then?

Comment: I've 20 quarter data, so `W1` can have values upto 60.
Even after current FY is over I need to sum from C2 onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula for C2

`=IF(W$1<3,0,SUM(C2:INDEX(C2:W2,W$1/3)))+INDEX(C2:W2,W$1/3+1)*MOD(W$1,3)/3`

That calculates how many whole quarters need to be included, then the partial ones. The IF function deals with small C1 values

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the heads up. 
@barry your formula has one misplaced parenthesis.
The corrected formula added below:
`=IF(W$1<3,0,SUM(C2:INDEX(C2:W2,W$1/3)))+INDEX(C2:W2,W$1/3+1)*MOD(W$1,3)/3`